# How do I clear inventories of unobtainable blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make commmand blocks that clear my players inventories of unobtainable blocks. I am trying to do `tile.moving_block.name` at the moment because that can be used for the horion commandblockexploit. I have tried
`/clear @a[tag=!staff] tile.moving_block.name`
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It’s actually pretty simple; you can easily put this command in a repeating command block:

```
clear @a unobtainable_block_name
```

Unfortunately you will have to do this for each individual block.

I’m guessing you are doing this for a realm/server. If this is the case I’d highly recommend the above command for beehives too as well, *and* I'd also kick cheating players out of the server automatically with this:

```
kick @a [name=!moderator_username, m=creative] IMAGINE HACKING
```

This will kick all players who are in creative and not a moderator

Comment: It should be impossible to go into creative without moderator power. Aside from that, the kick command only really works if you have a single moderator at anytime, since if you add two commands like that with two different names, anyone in creative will be kicked.

Comment: This doesnt work because minecraft thinks the unobtainable block names dont exist (as they shouldnt) and doesnt clear them. Kicking also doesnt work with indicators such as @a @e etc

Comment: If you have two moderators you simply do kick @a [name=!moderator_username, name=!2nd_moderator_username, m=creative] IMAGINE HACKING